# Why do we have $\lim_nE(\inf_{k\geq n}X_k)\leq\liminf_nE(X_n)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Why do we have $\lim_nE(\inf_{k\geq n}X_k)\leq\liminf_nE(X_n)$?

My try is that $\lim_nE(\inf_{k\geq n}X_k)= \liminf_nE(\inf_{k\geq n}X_k) \leq \liminf_nE(X_k) $.

Am I correct? This is part of the proof for Fatou's lemma...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which step do you not find completely convincing?

Comment: @Dap, thanks for the comment. I would say that the first equality that I wrote... $\lim_n E(\inf_{k\geq n} X_k)= \lim_{n->\infty}\inf_{k\geq n}E(\inf_{k\geq n} X_k)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\lim_n E(\inf_{k\ge n} X_k) = \liminf_n E(\inf_{k\ge n} X_k)$

This is true because $\lim_n a_n=\liminf a_n$ for any sequence $a_n$ (where $\lim_n a_n$ exists).

> $\liminf_n E(\inf_{k\ge n} X_k)\le \liminf_n  E(X_n)$

This is true because $\inf_{k\ge n} X_k\le X_n$, so $E(\inf_{k\ge n} X_k)\le EX_n$ for all $n$, implying the same inequality holds for the $\liminf$ (when $a_n\le b_n$, it follows $\liminf_n a_n\le \liminf_n b_n$).